# how to add new class in Cocos2d project using Xcode?

Tags: c++, xcode, cocos2d-x

I'm new to cocos2d dev and Xcode.

Now I want to add a C++ class in my cocos2d project, where the header file includes "cocos2d.h".

But it seems that the new header file is not related to cocos2d,
because it can't reference classes of cocos2d.

[image: img1]
[image: img2]

Comment: `new header file is not related to cocos2d` ?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: it is strange in the new header file, if you reference to a cocos2d class, such as Sprite, the class name should have changed its color, but actually it did not. And this-> could not reference any member function of Sprite.